# How can I get my iFrame to work with url from post_meta?

Tags: post-meta, iframe

I've made a custom meta box for adding an URL to the post, which can be displayed later on the frontend page. This url is inserted in my database correctly. Then I'm getting the url in my code by:

```
<?php
 $get_video_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true);
 //echo $get_video_url;
 //When I echo the variable, it's giving me te correct URL back for each post
?>
```

Now I'm trying to get my iFrame to work. But it gives me this error in console:
 `Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVoXDk8ps10' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'`.

What I know is that I have `watch?v=` inside the URL when it's get out of the database and for an iFrame the URL needs to be with `embed` like: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/OVoXDk8ps10`

**Question**
What my question is, is how I'm able to change the URL after I get it from the database and be able to get the iFrame to work on the frontend?

I'm using this code trying to displaying my iFrame:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="<?php echo $get_video_url; ?>" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

Comment: I'm not gonna post this as an answer because it does not actually answer your specific question but it's easier to use WP_Embed. Just get the global wp_embed first by putting `glbal $wp_embed;` anywhere above your video location (preferably on the top of the page) and then put `echo $wp_embed->run_shortcode( '[embed]' . $get_video_url  . '[/embed]' );`

Comment: Already fixed the problem, thanks for you comment and sorry for wasting you time.. @JeffreyvonGrumbkow

Comment: I'd still advice to use the integrated embed functionality but glad you got a solution :) BTW glbal is a typo, use `global $wp_embed;`

Comment: Aha, I will take a look at it. Thanks! @JeffreyvonGrumbkow

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow It is working like a charm! Using your suggestion now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every time when I post a question, I'm able to find the solution on the internet.. Sorry guys and girls for the spam!

**Solution**

```
<div class="featured-img-blog">

 <?php
  global $wp_embed;
  $get_video_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true);

  echo "<p align=center>" . $wp_embed->run_shortcode('[embed]' . $get_video_url . '[/embed]') . "</p>";
 ?>                               
</div>
```